# Delete an entry in a data file C++

Tags: c++, xml

In an XML .dat file, the format is like this:

```
//trees
<object id = "19" x = "834" y = "467" f = "0" />
<object id = "19" x = "823" y = "460" f = "0" />
<object id = "19" x = "825" y = "489" f = "0" />
<object id = "19" x = "821" y = "487" f = "2" />
<object id = "19" x = "825" y = "499" f = "2" />
//well
<object id = "28" x = "824" y = "470" f = "0" />
//statue
<object id = "16" x = "812" y = "473" f = "0" />
```

So it contains that information, an ID of a .3ds object and its location and the direction it should face.

In my project, I iterate through each line in the `.dat` file below and if the x and y values are the same as input, I want that line to be deleted.

```
// delete an object
void MapEditor::deleteObject(int xx, int zz){

    stringw path = Client::getCacheFile("Cache/Cache_file_3/models/object_test.dat");

    io::IXMLReader* reader = Client::device->getFileSystem()->createXMLReader(path);
    const stringw object("object");

    while (reader->read()) {
        switch (reader->getNodeType()) {
            //we found a new element
        case irr::io::EXN_ELEMENT:
            //new <object> tag
            if (object.equals_ignore_case(reader->getNodeName())) {
                u16 id = reader->getAttributeValueAsInt(L"id");
                u16 x = reader->getAttributeValueAsInt(L"x");
                u16 y = reader->getAttributeValueAsInt(L"y");

                // if the mouse click location matches an 
                    //object in the data file then execute the following
                if ((x == xx) && (y = zz)){
                    //cout << "we have a winner! Its ID is: " << id << endl; 
                    // this is where it would delete
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to delete the line that I want - will I need to copy the entire file to some string and perform a string replace on it? Or is there a better way

Comment: @Ian I have been trying to remove it via the constant set `const stringw object("object")` with `object.remove()` but it wants a string inside, I cant find any good sources for removing an XML element with `io::IXMLReader`

Comment: You *can't* delete something from the middle of a file. You can truncate the file or overwrite parts of it, but there no such thing as a line - it's just bytes that are treated as lines only when some code reads them. If you want to save the changes you made to an XML document, you'll have to overwrite the file in the same way you would with any other text format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay thanks, so is my best option to do a string replace on it? I was thinking if it is an XML node `<object>` each object would be stored as a separate entity - I could try turn it to a JSON array and remove the array index

Comment: No, as I said, you can't make modifications in the middle of a file, unless it involves overwriting a fixed number of **bytes**. Replacement *is* a modification, with an arbitrary length. Save the modified XML document over the old file. Or save the modified XML document to a temporary file, then swap them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually lots of questions on stack overflow about removing text in the middle of a file: [Remove memory from the middle of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496367/remove-memory-from-the-middle-of-a-file)

A file should be thought of as an array. Not a linked list. Just like an array you can't say, I want to remove elements 13 - 42 but leave the rest. Instead you must copy all the elements before and after into a newly allocated array.

That's the long answer to say: Yes you will need rewrite the file.